# Cannot locate libsdl2-2.o.so file

Tags: c++, shared-library, locate, sdl

I'm following an SDL C++ tutorial and they advised me to copy that file (libsdl2-2.o.so) into my project file to remove any errors occurring if the code was on a different computer. I have installed both libsdl2-2.0 and libsdl2-dev onto my machine, but cannot find their files in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (like in the tutorial). Is it maybe stored in a different location now, or what?

Note: I can run code including the SDL header with no problem, so it does exist on my computer, somewhere...

I did try

```
locate libsdl2-2.o.so
```

but with no luck

Comment: The [correct file name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libsdl2-2) is `libSDL2-2.0.so.0`. Also: 1. the link to tutorial and 2. ubuntu version would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The correct file name is `libSDL2-2.0.so.0` according to the search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libsdl2-2).